# Submit button in Symfony view without a reusable form type

Tags: forms, symfony, button, types, submit

In my Controller I have an action:

```
/**
     * @Route("/admin/tour/approve/{id}",name="approve_one_tour")
     */
    public function approveOneTourAction($id,Request $request)
    {
        $tour=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle:Tour')->findById($id);

        if ($request=='POST')
        {
            $tour->setStatus(true);
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($tour);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('manage_tour');
        }
        else {
            return $this->render('@HearWeGoHearWeGo/Manage/tour/approveonetour.html.twig', array('tour' => $tour));
        }
    }
```

In View:

```
{% extends('admin/admin.html.twig') %}

{% block mainpageheader %}
    <h1 class="page-heading">APPROVE TOUR</h1>
{% endblock %}


{% block mainpagecontainerheader %}
    <h3 class="block-title">Approve {{ tour.name }}</h3>
{% endblock %}

{% block mainpagecontainer %}
    <div class="block">
        <div class="block-content">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 50px;">#</th>
                    <th style="width:15%">Name</th>
                    <th style="width:15%">Company</th>
                    <th style="width:15%">Destination</th>
                    <th style="width:20px">Start Date</th>
                    <th style="width:20px">End Date</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Discount</th>
                    <th style="width:40%">Info</th>
                    <th style="width:20px">Submission Date</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">{{ tour.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ tour.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ tour.company.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ tour.destination.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ tour.startdate|date('Y-m-d') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ tour.enddate|date('Y-m-d') }}</td>
                        <td>{{ tour.price }}</td>
                        <td>{{ tour.discount }}</td>
                        <td>{{ tour.info|raw }}</td>
                        <td>{{ tour.createdAt|date('Y-m-d') }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <form action="{{ path('approve_one_tour',{'id':tour.id}) }}" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Approve"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

When the button is clicked, nothing happens

Because I only want to show the data of a `Tour` entity object, not allow the user to edit it, so I think I needn't create a Form Type that adds editable and reusable attributes. The only thing I need is a button, when I click the button, the only attribute of `Tour` entity needs changing is `status`, from `false` (default) to `true`. Is there any way? If any, please help fix my code above

Comment: why is it that your form method is POST?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mistyped
It should have been
`if ($request->getMethod()=='POST')`
After I fixed that, it run smoothly, the others are kept the same
Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all use `$request->getMethod()==` instead of `$request` if you want to check the request method.
You can create a form with just a submit button like so.

```
//in your controller
protected function createForm(){
  $ff = $this->get('form.factory'); // get the form factory service, or inject it in
  $builder = $ff->createBuilder('form');
  $builder->add('submit', 'submit');

  return $builder->getForm();
}

public function approveOneTourAction(Request $request, $id){
  $form = $this->createForm();
  $form->handleRequest($request);
  if($form->isValid() && $form['submit']->isClicked()){
    // ... do what you want with the tour here
  }

  return $this->render('@HearWeGoHearWeGo/Manage/tour/approveonetour.html.twig', array('tour' => $tour, 'form' => $form->createView()));

}
```

---

Then render the form passed as `form` to your template as explained in [Symfony forms Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-the-form)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mistyped
It should have been
`if ($request->getMethod()=='POST')`
After I fixed that, it run smoothly, the others are kept the same
Anyway, thank you!